# Retrieve windows user name of client who browses my asp.net web application

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I know there are other similar questions, but none of the answers helped me.
I have an ASP.NET web application hosted in IIS on a server.
The server has a windows operating system with a windows user name, suppose: ServerDomain/ServerUserName.
I have a Main.aspx page. The page has a link tag:

```
<a href="#" class="linkbutton" onclick="resendHandle(this)">Resend</a>
```

The page has a script tag and there I have a Java Script function:

```
 function resendHandle(el) {
      var clientWindowsName = ?
      alert(clientWindowsName );
      setCurrentUser(clientWindowsName));
      submit();
 }
```

Now suppose a client, who also has a windows operating system with a Windows user name: ClientXDomain/ClientXUserName is browsing my site.
Once he clicks the Resend link, the control flows to resendHandle Java Script function and after "submit" to the Resend method in Main.aspx.cs (behind code file). In this method, I want to retrieve the client windows user name, which is: ClientXDomain/ClientXUserName. Obviously, the aspx.cs is a server code, so if I check there for user identity in this method, I will get: ServerDomain/ServerUserName. But as I've mentioned, I want to get the: ClientXDomain/ClientXUserName in this method.
The clientWindowsName is accessed from the server method with the help of setCurrentUser, so there is no problem for me to transfer the clientWindowsName variable value (within the resendHandle java script function) to the server size.
The problem is that

```
alert(clientWindowsName );
```

always returns NULL for me for:

```
var clientWindowsName = '<%=Page.User.Identity.Name%>';
```

and for other options I've tried.
Only for:

```
var clientWindowsName = '<%=Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name.ToString()%>';
```

it alerts NT AUTHORITYIUSR.

but none of the options gives me the desired user name: ClientXDomain/ClientXUserName.

So, how do I get it? Note that I'm trying to get the value within a Java Script function, maybe I should try to do outside the script tag. Thanks!

EDIT 01: My web config contains:

```
 <authentication mode="Windows"/>
```

Comment: please check my answer hope it will be useful . We are using this in our project and both windows authentication and impersonation  should be used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable impersonation  which will help you to get loggined user identity .
in web.config or it can be set on IIS server please check how to set it .But this is what you are missing .

```
 <identity impersonate="true" />
```

Hi you need to set impersonation as well this way if user is in active   directory then his identity can be passed to code otherwise you will get the identity on account  under which it is hosted under IIS.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa292118(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to configure your website using WIndows Authentication instead of Form authentication, like this https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/94612/Windows-Authentication

Comment: Thanks, but I'm already using authentication mode="Windows" in my web config, see Edit 01 in my question.

Answer (score 0):

I had to disable Anonymous Authentication.